# Is it possible to specify the Flutter SDK path for the VSCODE extension?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am having the setup that my flutter-sdk lives inside the projects root because I am using a version management system (FVM). When I run my programs from the console I run 'fvm flutter run' from the console but I also want to be able to start a debugging session with that SDK in the projects root ...
therefore my question is if it is possible to specify the SDK path for launching a Flutter App in debug mode and if how would i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In vscode press ctrl+shift+p, search for 'set flutter sdk', and you can identify your Flutter installations and dart as well. You can edit this manually also in the settings.json.

You can try this, and create a `launch.json`, by going to `Run` in VScode menu, then `Add Configurations`,

add the following, mind you, your project's directories.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "name": "YOUR APP NAME",
            "cwd": "/home/u/Projects/fireflutter/live-projects/YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER/",
            "type": "dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "flutterMode": "debug",
            "args": [
                // "--web-port",
                // "8080",
                // "--no-sound-null-safety",
                // pass your arguments here, whatever you would type 
                //in the terminal when you would use i.e 
                //flutter run --no-sound-null-safety[I love null safety by the way, 
                //but this is a common problem for people who still want to opt out of it.
            ],
        }
    ],
    "dart.flutterSdkPath": "/home/u/Downloads/sdks/flutter",
    "dart.sdkPath": "/home/u/Downloads/sdks/flutter/bin/dart",
}
```

If you get an error saying `Error: spawn /bin/sh ENOENT`, it means that your path is incorrect, and you have to fix either your `program` or `cwd` or `name`. Please update on the result of this.

Comment: First off - thanks for responding. Changing Flutter SDK path works but to synchronize settings with my team I would prefer the settings.json version. Though when running a debug session it just ignores my settings.json whatever I put in there. Can you give an example code snippet?

Comment: You're most welcome, I'll post shortly a snippet for your launch json. Basically in your `.vscod` folder in your project, you need to create a `launch.json' file. In that file you pass the arguments you want to launch the debugger with. And pass flags uch as `--no-sound-null-safety` or your flutter SDK path. The same path you specified in your `settings.json`

Comment: I added a snippet @NiklasvonHaxthausen , kindly check it out and update if it helps.

Comment: My man, I also learned something new while answering your question in detail, happy coding!